# How to create venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv, python-3.10

I have been using my python v3.9 in my virtual environment, it contains all the packages and scripts i have been using for so long. But, now with the release of python v 3.10 it installed itself globally though I wanted it to be installed in same venv I was using for python v3.9 So, if anyone could help me with how can I install python v3.10 in the same venv of my v3.9 . My IDE is PyCharm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put all the dependencies of your python 3.9 (venv) in requirements.txt file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Create a new folder then move that file inside the newly created folder
then execute the following code, it will create a new virtual environment with python 3.10

```
python -m venv newenv
```

activate the newly created environment by

```
source newenv/bin/activate
```

then install the required dependencies by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note: If your OS do not have 'venv' module then simply install it by using

```
pip install venv
```

Comment: its creating a new venv with python v 3.9 instead of python v 3.10 , though i changed the interpreter to v3.10

Comment: It's seem like you have installed python v3.9 as globally or you can have multiple python version in your os system, to crosscheck that simply do googling in my case it is ~usr/bin/local/ once you got the file simply delete the python 3.9

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

A virtual environment includes a copy of Python binaries. It can't be both 3.9 and 3.10.

You must create a 3.10 venv.

What you can do is get a list of all libs in your 3.9 venv and install them in your 3.10 venv.

```
# In 3.9 venv
pip freeze > requirements.txt
# In 3.10 venv
pip install -r requirements.txt
```